# Linux Two network adapters with static IP addresses on GCE Linux instance

Tags: linux, networking, debian, kvm-virtualization, google-compute-engine

I want to make a VM hosted on Google Compute Engine to have 2 static IP addresses. For the purpose I created the VM having two network adapters (NICs) each of them allowing me to "pick" 1 static IP address from their respective networks. That's the only possible way to make a VM to have 2 addresses, as the GCE docs say. Cannot have one adapter with more than one static address :(

What I was able to achieve until now is to make only one of the IPs to "work" at a time. Never both of them.
The system is Debian and my `/etc/network/interfaces` is the following:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.0.1.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.0.1.0
        broadcast 10.0.1.255
        gateway 10.0.1.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        dns-search example.com


auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.0.2.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.0.2.0
        broadcast 10.0.2.255
```

... despite `'ifconfig'` output says that everything is okay and even shows traffic on both of the interfaces (and NICs) there can never be a contact to both of the IPs (`10.0.1.2` and `10.0.2.2` in the same time). I can only connect to either `10.0.1.2` or `10.0.2.2` from outside, depending on which one I put to be eth0 and restart networking:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:01:0a:00:01:02
          inet addr:10.0.1.2  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2552 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2553 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:306760 (306.7 KB)  TX bytes:1392278 (1.3 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:01:0a:00:02:02
          inet addr:10.0.2.2  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:621 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:51913 (51.9 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:149 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:149 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:44874 (44.8 KB)  TX bytes:44874 (44.8 KB)
```

`lshw -class network` shows:

```
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Virtio network device
       vendor: Red Hat, Inc
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 00
       serial: 42:01:0a:00:01:02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=virtio_net driverversion=1.0.0 ip=10.0.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
       resources: irq:10 ioport:c040(size=64) memory:febfe000-febfe03f
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Virtio network device
       vendor: Red Hat, Inc
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 00
       serial: 42:01:0a:00:02:02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=virtio_net driverversion=1.0.0 ip=10.0.2.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
       resources: irq:10 ioport:c080(size=64) memory:febff000-febff03f
```

P.S.
I am adding the result from command `iptables -nvL`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1578 packets, 354K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 8781  544K f2b-dovecot-pop3imap  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 110,995,143,993
 1132 61887 f2b-pureftpd  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 21
 1457  564K f2b-postfix-sasl  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25
20120 2175K f2b-sshd   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
11287  688K f2b-dovecot-pop3imap  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 110,995,143,993
 1511 82441 f2b-pureftpd  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 21
 1773  585K f2b-postfix-sasl  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25
30811 3348K f2b-sshd   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
12528  760K f2b-dovecot-pop3imap  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 110,995,143,993
 1691 92225 f2b-pureftpd  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 21
 1960  632K f2b-postfix-sasl  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25
36156 3948K f2b-sshd   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
16013  963K f2b-dovecot-pop3imap  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 110,995,143,993
 2352  128K f2b-pureftpd  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 21
 2656  846K f2b-postfix-sasl  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25
48399 5280K f2b-sshd   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1735 packets, 987K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain f2b-dovecot-pop3imap (4 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
48609 2955K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain f2b-postfix-sasl (4 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 7846 2628K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain f2b-pureftpd (4 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 6669  364K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain f2b-sshd (4 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   22  1728 REJECT     all  --  *      *       52.21.230.131        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   22  1728 REJECT     all  --  *      *       185.207.232.232      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   22  1728 REJECT     all  --  *      *       136.159.103.234      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   17  1232 REJECT     all  --  *      *       118.97.22.162        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
 132K   15M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Also there's the output from the command `route`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.1.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

How to make both IPs and both NICs to work. There is no ping to either one of them from outside, depending on which eth is listed first in `/etc/network/interfaces` ?

Comment: to me it seems you are missing the gateway IP in eth1 (10.0.2.1?) as without a gateway the traffic can't get out of that network (10.0.2.0/24).

Comment: Thanx. I did try with the gateway there. Result was the same. I ended up without a gateway on eth1 because it would seem the machine not to have unambiguous route out

Comment: check with traceroute where your traffic is going, and when you say "from outside" you mean what exactly? have you two different external IPs attached to the VM NICs?

Comment: @Zina Yes, I do have 2 different static IPs attached to the NICs. traceroute shows inside-out traffic is going thru eth0. When I say "from outside", I mean when I try to ping the IPs from another machine. Basically that is what I need. Both IPs to be attached to my machine and accessible from outside-in. This happens indeed, but only separately. Cannot make both addresses work altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did manage to do it. The following article helped me:
https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System

For the purpose of the two NICs to work at the same time with a different gateways, we need a second routing table. Let's name it `rt2`. Please follow the procedure:

1. Ensure you have the `iproute2` installed:
   `sudo apt-get install iproute2`
2. Add second routing table by editing `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`, add the following line to the file:

   `1 rt2`
3. Make sure the second interface `eth1` **does not** have a `gateway` defined
4. In `/etc/network/interfaces` add the following lines to the second interface `eth1`:

   `post-up ip route add 10.0.2.0/24 dev eth1 src 10.0.2.2 table rt2
   post-up ip route add default via 10.0.2.1 dev eth1 table rt2
   post-up ip rule add from 10.0.2.2/32 table rt2
   post-up ip rule add to 10.0.2.2/32 table rt2`

Changes are permanent and after a reboot, I do have both the IP addresses reachable from outside-in (incoming). When making connections from inside-out (outgoing) the `eth0` is used, as it is the default.

My final `/etc/network/interfaces` now looks like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.0.1.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.0.1.0
        broadcast 10.0.1.255
        gateway 10.0.1.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        dns-search example.com


auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.0.2.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.0.2.0
        broadcast 10.0.2.255
        ###################################################################### gateway 10.0.2.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        dns-search example.com
        post-up ip route add 10.0.2.0/24 dev eth1 src 10.0.2.2 table rt2
        post-up ip route add default via 10.0.2.1 dev eth1 table rt2
        post-up ip rule add from 10.0.2.2/32 table rt2
        post-up ip rule add to 10.0.2.2/32 table rt2
```

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance you're missing:

```
    gateway 10.0.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

for the second adapter. Also, what's your output of the following:

> iptables -nvL
>
> route

Comment: Thanx, I added gateway and nameservers the first time. This appear not to be the problem. I decided to remove the gateway from the second eth. Now I put it again. No change. The behavior is absolutely the same. Also I did added what you ask for, by editing my question above.